# How to move non-temp files to dedicated subdirectories?

Tags: powershell

I need help building a script that goes through each file in the root of the current directory, comparing their filename.ext against a blacklist of masks to exclude (*.!qb, *.parts, etc). The unmatched files are sent to their dedicated directories using syntax `filename\filename.ext`

My old batch code is not powershell ready but may provide some clarity.

```
for %%s in (*.*) do if not "%%~xs"==".!qB" if not "%%~xs"==".parts" (
md "%%~ns" & move "%%s" "%%~ns\")
```

Please help me understand the commands needed to replace these.

Comment: I'm mean to present only aliases: `gci * | ? Extension -notin '.!qb','.parts' | % {md $_.BaseName;$_|move $_.BaseName}` look them up with `Get-Alias`

Comment: move : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take 
pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
At line:1 char:67

Comment: The command works but tries to also move the directories, change to `gci * -file | ...`

Comment: no, still says something is wrong with the `move` command being piped. I confirmed it's only feeding it the files now.

Comment: `InvalidArgument: (D:\source\TheTestFile.mkv:PSObject) [Move-Item], Parameter 
   BindingException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slightly changed command from comment.

```
gci * -file | ? Extension -notin '.!qb','.parts' | % {md $_.BaseName ;move $_.FullName -Destination ("{0}\" -f $_.BaseName) -force}
```

More verbose variant:

```
Get-ChildItem * -File | 
  Where-Object Extension -notin '.!qb','.parts' | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item  $_.BaseName -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    Move-Item -LiteralPath $_.FullName -Destination ("{0}\" -f $_.BaseName) -force
  }
```

sample tree after running script:

```
> tree /f
A:.
│   filename.!qb
│   filename.parts
│
└───filename
        filename.mkv
```

Comment: Instead of creating an empty directory by name of `filename\` it seems to be trying to rename the files into `filename` because I lost the extensions. plus I think you meant to write `SilentlyContinue`. I will investigate more later.

Comment: Typo corrected. And the item without extension is **NOT** the directory you wanted to have with the file inside?

Comment: `SilentlyContinue` is still written wrong. Item without extension IS my preferred directory name but this script does not create a directory at all but instead renames the file itself to have no extension.

Comment: There was another typo :-( and the -EA 0 suppressed that error.

Comment: It now works but only for files that do not have this type of `[` `]` brackets in the filename. Files that do have brackets only get the directory but are not moved.

Comment: That is caused by PowerShell's [wildcard/Ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1) feature, use `-Literalpath` see latest edit of the answert.

Comment: I am learning what I an from this working code but can you explain where this `"{0}\"`comes from?

Comment: `"{0}\" -f $_.BaseName` uses the [-f format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) to append the trailing backslash to the Basename.